# How to tell Microsoft Edge what it should display in reading mode

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Reading mode in Spartan/Edge seems to choose, somehow, which div on the site to display in reading mode. In many pages, it does not find the appropriate div (like bbc.co.uk). 
However, [on our site](http://dancesportinfo.net/Competition/danceComp_Wuppertal_2015_28971/WDSF_Rising_Stars_Standard_411203/Results), it enables reading mode, but then displays the completely wrong part of the page.

So - how can I tell it to take the right part or at least how to disable it on those pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find information on how to optimize reading view, as well as how to opt-out, here: http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/readingview/

**07/10: Edit to include specific information**

Specifically, you may be interested in optimizing your title, body, and image markup to ensure a good reading mode experience.

**Title**

Your page should include a `<title>` element in the header. In addition, you should include a `<meta title="">` tag that matches your main heading in your content section.

**Body text**

Ensure your main content does not include a lot of deeply nested elements and that font-sizes and other styles are uniform. Style variations for things like pull quotes, etc. should still be fine.

**Images**

The first eligible image becomes the dominant image of the article. The dominant image is rendered as the first piece of content and given full column width. All following images are rendered as inline images within the article.

Images are recommended to be wrapped in `<figure>` tags with no more than two `<figcaption>` tags.

**Opting out**

Including this `meta` tag will disable reading mode in IE11 and, currently, Microsoft Edge.

```
<meta name="IE_RM_OFF" content="true">
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RickSmith: Good call. I've updated my answer to include specific tips.

Comment: Worth noting: that linked page has, indeed, changed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Tag

```
<meta name="IE_RM_OFF" content="true">
```

Check the Below for more details
http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/readingview/

Comment: The link is dead! Can anyone point to the new location, if such exist?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/browser-features/reading-view