# How a page is qualified for reading mode in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

When one navigates a website in Edge, it will be nice to see ‘reading view’ button is enabled. Like to have some understanding on how a page is qualified for reading mode.  This will help developers to have reading mode in mind when they develop the website.

Comment: Are you asking a question, or just making a suggestion about Microsoft Edge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell Microsoft Edge what it should display in reading mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295693/how-to-tell-microsoft-edge-what-it-should-display-in-reading-mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is from a Microsoft Edge PM. Reading view is automatically enabled when:

- There is no ***pre*** tag
- There is enough content
- The page is not the top root page of a site

Comment: "not the root page of a site".
That's just weird. Why would that not be available??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what he means by "not the root page of a site."
But I found out that if I go to `http://sitename.com` no reading page view appears.
But if I go to `http://sitename.com/index.htm` the reading page view does appear.
Of if I go to `http://sitename.com` and click on a nav item, then return to the home page, then the reading view will appear.