# Immersive reader deactivate javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can we deactivate or prevent the immersive reader from Edge browser using Javascript? For instance, for an article on our website, we would like to disable immersive reader mode.

Comment: For example, I would like to be able to deactivate the reader in an article on my website with a Javascript

Comment: Have any a Idea?

Comment: Have any a idea?

Comment: Here is there answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295693/how-to-tell-microsoft-edge-what-it-should-display-in-reading-mode